# iPhone SDK: Observe current time of AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ipad, avaudioplayer

is there a best practice for getting an event on every second of playback of an AVAudioPlayer instance? I need to change a view automatically depending on the current playback time.

Thank You!

Comment: You realize there is a `currentTime` property of AVAudioPlayer, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could start one or more instances of NSTimer when playback starts, and change the view when the timer(s) fire.